# NUnit-share data between tests for different modules

Tags: c#, singleton, nunit

I have a VS-solution with a number of projects. Each project has a unit test project associated with it. Say for example that project A and B have the unit test projects A.Test and B.Test, respectively.

Tests in both unit test projects depend on (the same) data that has to be loaded from a file, and it is quite some data that need to be read each time. The overall time for running all unit tests (+1500) would be significantly reduced if I did not have reread the data from file for every unit test.

I had an idea to create a TestDataManager as a Singleton and let it read the data the first time it requested and cache the data in memory. The next time the same data is requested, the manager just returns the data that is already cached. This works as expected for unit tests within the same project (say A.Test) but when the TestDataManager is called from a test in B.Test, the manager has been torn down and recreated.

Does anybody know how to resolve the problem to keep data in memory when changing between unit test projects?

Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

It requires you to be running both assemblies in the same run and in the same AppDomain. Some runners (e.g. nunit3-console) allow you to set up options to do this. Others, like the NUnit 3 VS adapter, do not.

Comment: Just setup a public static class both modules and see and place a public static property on it.  In your [SetUp] if the property is null, initialize it.

Comment: If your tests are not in the same MMB e process and appdomain ¹they will be initialized twice. Read the question.